# How does someone become a user of my application?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, real-time, subscription

I'm trying to learn how to use the realtime update API. As far as I understand, if I create a subscription for my application to the object type "user", I will get an update whenever **a user of my application** changes one of the specified fields.

So the questuon is: Who is a user of my application? When does one become my application's user? Is it when he/she uses it the first time? Is it when he/she *installs* it? Do I get updates only if the changes happen while the user is logged in? Etc.

I'd like to understant the exact answer in each of the following cases:
- a Website
- a native or desktop app
- an app on facebook
- a page tab

I can't find any of this explained in the Documentation.

Thanks in advance
m.

Answer (score 0):

it is when he/she installs it.
when it change something on facebook profile, your url will be pinged(you must set in app settings) take a read here http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/realtime/

Comment: I already read that page of the documentation, and it doesn't say a word about what makes someone a user of the application.

In the case of a website, what does "he/she installs it" mean?